# How to add require() in HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, html, npm, require, html5boilerplate

I am trying to add require() in HTML5 boilerplate but it doesn't work.

 **I get error - `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in browser console.**

I did `npm i require`, then -

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jquery": true,
        "mocha":true,
        "amd": true
    },
    "plugins": ["mocha"],
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
      "indent": ["error", 2],
      "quotes": ["error", "single"],
      "semi": ["error", "always"]
    }
};
```

main.js -

```
const Swal = require('sweetalert2');
// other stuff
```

Edit - Added this also to q
Here's my package.json -

```
{
  // other stuff

  "dependencies": {
    "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running your code on a browser?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/6852641

Comment: I checked that answer before and tried, didn't seem to work.

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code then (package.json, html files, webpack config or whatever other bundler you're using)

Comment: Added package.json 
Everything else is just the same as HTML5 boilerplate - https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate 
Whatever changes I made in code are above

Comment: You can use import instead of require see: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/ I think you shouldn't add require by npm it should be already as part of node. Browser won't run require!!! You have to transpile the code first.